# rust cvs: invalid enum value

Tags: csv, rust, serde

I am trying to use rust [csv](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.6/csv/cookbook/index.html) crate to deserialize simple csv string into the rust struct:

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use stringreader::StringReader;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum MatchOutcomeCSV {
    win,
    loss,
    draw,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MatchResultCSV {
    team1: String,
    team2: String,
    status: MatchOutcomeCSV,
}
```

However when I try to deserialize simple input string `"Allegoric Alaskans;Blithering Badgers;win"` I get the following error from deserialization:

```
(invalid enum value) 0
```

For deserialization I use the following code:

```
ReaderBuilder::new()
  .delimiter(b';')
  .has_headers(false)
  .from_reader(StringReader::new(match_results))
  .deserialize()
  .map(|x| x.unwrap())
  .into_iter()
  .collect()
```

I wonder what is the issue and how can one properly parse the struct I have above?

**Edit**:

Included my `Cargo.toml` for clarification around `stringreader` package:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
csv = "1.1"
stringreader = "0.1.1"
```

Comment: Could you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I tried to run your code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d406862655dcae932f537a69b93634c8) but everything works there. Maybe it is related to the `StringReader` you are using, which I could not find anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it @jonasbb. I included my Cargo toml to clarify usage of `stringreader `. Main reason was to use buffer that can be created from a string.

Comment: The `StringReader` does not seem to be the problem. You don't really need it though, since `&[u8]` implements `Read`.